# Conservation of Momentum vs. Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

If a mass $m$ travelling at velocity $v$ collides ideally with a massless shaft mounted on a massless bearing with an identical mass on the other end of the shaft:

Conservation of momentum requires the velocity after the collision to be $\frac{v}{2}$, and the angular velocity to be $\frac{v}{2L}$ where $L$ is the radius of rotation.

Kinetic energy of the system then becomes $\frac{mv^2}{4}$ which is a 50% loss of energy. Where has it gone? I always understood that inelastic collision losses are attributed to deformation, heat etc. However this obviously is not the case here -energy loss is fundamental- I guess.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I can't understand the setup.  Can you provide a diagram?  If the shaft is massless, is all the energy just in the rotation of the mass?

Comment: Collides ideally?

Comment: If a stationary mass starts rotating, then you need to investigate the angular momentum of the system. Is the bearing mounted in the center of the shaft and each mass is L/2 from the bearing?  Your setup is extremely unclear!

Comment: I don't think this ideal set-up can conserve (linear) momentum. Some of it leaks out through the bearing into whatever affixes the bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you taking into account the rotational kinetic energy?

When it begins rotating, the kinetic energy is no longer just $\frac{mv^2}{2}$, but $\frac{Iω^2}{2} + \frac{mv^2}{2}$.